# Build local Hoogle DB despite error in Haddock

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, haddock, hoogle

Is there a workaround to build a lokal Hoogle DB despite Haddock errors in some packages. For example, is there a workaround on how to exclude those packages from the Haddock sub-task during the lokal Hoogle DB build?

As a concret example:

```sh
$ stack hoogle
No Hoogle database yet. Automatically building haddocks and hoogle database (use --no-setup to disable) ...
classy-prelude-yesod-1.5.0: configure
classy-prelude-yesod-1.5.0: build
classy-prelude-yesod-1.5.0: haddock
Progress 1/2

--  While building package classy-prelude-yesod-1.5.0 using:
      /Users/nrm/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-osx/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_2.4.0.1_ghc-8.6.4 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-2.4.0.1 haddock --html --hoogle --html-location=../$pkg-$version/ --haddock-option=--hyperlinked-source --haddock-option=--quickjump
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
    Logs have been written to: /Users/nrm/Sources/mdpm/projects/Yapper/.stack-work/logs/classy-prelude-yesod-1.5.0.log

    Configuring classy-prelude-yesod-1.5.0...
    Preprocessing library for classy-prelude-yesod-1.5.0..
    Building library for classy-prelude-yesod-1.5.0..
    [1 of 2] Compiling ClassyPrelude.Yesod ( src/ClassyPrelude/Yesod.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/ClassyPrelude/Yesod.o )
    [2 of 2] Compiling Paths_classy_prelude_yesod ( .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/autogen/Paths_classy_prelude_yesod.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/Paths_classy_prelude_yesod.o )
    Preprocessing library for classy-prelude-yesod-1.5.0..
    Running Haddock on library for classy-prelude-yesod-1.5.0..
    Haddock coverage:
    haddock: internal error: internal: extractDecl
    CallStack (from HasCallStack):
      error, called at utils/haddock/haddock-api/src/Haddock/Interface/Create.hs:1116:12 in main:Haddock.Interface.Create
```

Relates to [How to build with haddocks, but ignore haddock errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52724952/how-to-build-with-haddocks-but-ignore-haddock-errors)

Comment: Seems to be this bug: https://github.com/haskell/haddock/issues/979.

Answer (score 0):

`stack hoogle` is approximately a helper around `stack haddock` then `hoogle generate --local`. If you can generate Haddock output only for the projects that work then you can manually `hoogle generate --local`. However, I'm not aware of any way to restrict `stack haddock` to only a subset, so it may not be practical.

Another approach is to `hoogle generate <list of dependencies>`, which will use the remote documentation rather than local, and thus will skip running Haddock.

Comment: Where `stack hoogle` terminates with an error, `hoogle generate` runs through. `hoogle generate --local` terminates with error `Starting generate \n Reading ghc-pkg... hoogle: ghc-pkg: createProcess: runInteractiveProcess: exec: does not exist (No such file or directory)`, though.

Comment: That says that `ghc-pkg` isn't on your path, perhaps because you don't have a global install of GHC and are only using it through Stack? You may need to do `stack exec -- hoogle generate --local` where `stack exec` will put `ghc-pkg` on your path and point at the right package databases.